# How to fix the webview to correctly show the elements on web page?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, webview, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress site build on "gutenberg" and it does not display the word "Menu" correctly in the webview, it seems to be slightly outside the left screen, in a Chrome mobile browser there are not thats errors, all elements (word Menu) is in place, all is displayed correctly, but not so in Webview How to fix it?
I use the android 4.4 kitkat on GalaxyGrand 2 i tested only this phone!
(https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2hHz/25DMkxh3U) this is code files you can download and see or use it free!

Comment: Depending on the version of Android, the WebViews are generally using the same render engine as Chrome mobile browser. [Edit] your post with how you are testing, what devices and which version of Android each runs.

Comment: I updated my post, please check it.

Comment: Android 4.4 is old (almost 7 years). That version of Android used the webview render engine that came with the OS and could only be updated with OS updates. Unless you are required to support such a old device, I would recommend raising any minSDK to at least Android 5.0 (API 21) if not higher.